# How to auto update a Listview - .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, .net-maui

I am making an application where there is a history and I want the history to be updated automatically when there is a change in my list.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using view models, just bind your `ListView` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` in the view model via the `ItemsSource` dependency property - when the collection changes, the view will update as well. (And if you're not already using MVVM, I'd suggest moving to it ASAP.)

Comment: This is not true; it does not work.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough: Well I use it quite a lot in my app with no problems... so rather than just asserting it doesn't work, I'd suggest adding a question that reproduces the issue.

Comment: The problem seems to be that 'binding' doesn't work and you have to set the `.ItemsSource` in code. The next problem is that if you update one of the items then you have to create and assign a new `.ItemsSource` to get the thing to show the changes.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough: Again, that's not my experience - in either of those aspects. Again, if you create a new question with a way of reproducing the problem, it's likely we can help you. Just claiming that I'm not telling the truth (as if I don't know what I do in my own app) doesn't help.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough: I've just reproduced it working with a trivial application. I can put that on GitHub if you'd like to verify it for yourself...